# Preciso preencher 2 campos usando select

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho um `select` com os seguintes valores no `option`:

```
<select id="frutas" name="frutas" >
     <option value="">Selecione...</option>
     <option value="Maçã - 10.00"> Maçã </option>
     <option value="Banana - 15.00"> Banana </option>                      
</select>
```

Ao selecionar uma opção, os dados são preenchidos em um campo `text` com o ID: `nome_preco`:

```
<input type="text" id="nome_preco"  name="nome_preco" value="" />
```

Estou precisando preencher um outro campo mas só com o preço da fruta:

```
<input type="text" id="preco"  name="preco" value="" />
```

Então se eu seleciono "`Maçã`", meus campos seriam preenchidos com os dados:

Fruta: **`Maçã - 10.00`**

Valor: **`10.00`**

Como posso fazer isso? Seria possível fazer isso utilizando jQuery? Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja abaixo o código em funcionamento:

```js
$('#frutas').change(function(){
     
     $('#preco').val($('#frutas').val());
  
     $('#nome').val($('#frutas option:selected').text());
  
     $('#nome_preco').val($('#frutas option:selected').text() + ' - ' + $(this).val());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="frutas" name="frutas" >
     <option value="">Selecione...</option>
     <option value="10.00">Maçã</option>
     <option value="15.00">Banana</option>                      
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
Preço<br/>
<input type="text" id="preco"  name="preco" value="" />

<br/>
<br/>
Nome<br/>
<input type="text" id="nome"  name="nome" value="" />     

<br/>
<br/>
Nome + preço:<br/>
<input type="text" id="nome_preco"  name="nome_preco" value="" />
```

Comment: muito obrigada! Funcionou direitinho!